# Gulp. How to remove duplicated functions decelerations in merged file

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I use 'gulp-concat' to merge several files into a single one.
However, overwrite files are present. These files contain functions that are already declared. The previously declared functions should be deleted in this case. Is there a way to filter this out?

Example:

**script**

```
concat = require('gulp-concat')

gulp.src(['file1', 'file2'])
.pipe(concat('merge'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
```

**file1**

```
function A () {...}
function B () {return x}
function C () {...}
```

**file2**

```
function B () {return y}
function D () {...}
function E () {...}
```

**merge**

```
function A () {...}
function B () {return x}
function C () {...}
function B () {return y}
function D () {...}
function E () {...}
```

**What I want to have:**

```
function A () {...}
function C () {...}
function B () {return y}
function D () {...}
function E () {...}
```

Does anyone know a plugin or solution to fix my problem?